# Is a class that implements an interface also an interface?

Tags: java, class, interface

I was under the impression that when a class implements an interface it is implementing abstract methods, therefore making them usable, non-abstract, methods. My boss contends that a class that implements an interface is also an interface. This does not make sense to me. The class implementing the interface is not abstract and not labelled an interface. Can someone give their input on this?

Comment: No. A class can never be an interface. They are the same ***type*** yes, but again, a class cannot be an interface. Period. One of you is misinterpreting what the other is saying.

Comment: If at all, this should be on programmers.SE as it's not about a specific programming problem. More likely, point your boss to the official documentation.

Comment: I suppose a rather absurd example might be comparing this to classifying a taxon in biology. A taxon defines a population of organisms (e.g. a *type* of population). If a creature is a member of that taxon, does that make that creature a taxon, the same way that if a class implements an interface it makes the class an interface? (An admittedly bad example, but I'm not a creative person...)

Comment: @user3580294 You have to have a PhD to understand that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not sure if I follow... Is it a mistake I made (more likely), or just an incomprehensible example?

Comment: @user3580294 I was bad at biology :p

Comment: I think your boss is right, but only if you really want a raise next time you ask.  Also, his tie is fantastic and that comb-over over his bald spot is really stylish.

Comment: Either you misunderstand your boss, or your boss is wrong. I would seek clarification, and look at this as a learning opportunity: sometimes the people you report to are hopelessly clueless, and you have to deal with it the best you can.

Answer (score 2):

A `class` is not an `interface`.<sup>*</sup>  That doesn't change just because the class implements an interface.

However, an *instance* of a class that implements an interface, is also an *instance* of that interface.

The big difference, and the one that seems to be miscommunicated here, is the difference between classes and objects.

Let's say we have this code:

```
public interface Animal {
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public static void main() {
        Animal rover = new Dog();
    }
}
```

There are things we can and can't say about the relationship between the stuff defined here.

We **can** say (assuming "is (a/an)" is short for "is an instance of"):

- "A `Dog` is an `Animal`."
- "`rover`  is a `Dog`."
- "`rover` is an `Animal`."
- "`Dog` is a (subtype/subclass/implementation) of `Animal`."
- "`Dog` (*presents/provides/implements*) an interface."<sup>*</sup>

We **can not** say:

- "`Dog` is an `interface`."  (No, `Dog` is a class.)<sup>*</sup>
- "`Dog` is an `Animal`." (See above. Note the difference between "`Dog`" and "**a** `Dog`".)

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> From a semantic POV, it could be argued that *every* class is an interface. But that argument has nothing to do with the `interface` keyword; it relies on the traditional definition of the word.  And it would apply to *all* classes, regardless of whether the class `implements SomeInterface`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A class is not an interface, but an instance of a class will be an implementation of any interfaces implemented by the class, and reference to an instance of the class will thus be a reference to an implementation of the interface.  Consequently, a value of class type may be assigned to a variable of interface type without a cast if the class in question implements the interface.  If the class in question does not implement the interface, code may use an explicit cast to request that Java attempt the conversion anyway.  If the variable happens to hold a reference to an instance of a derived class which does implement the interface, the cast will succeed; otherwise it will throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

a class is never an interface. it's an implementation of an interface, which will help you in 'programming to interfaces'.

they can be user interfaces, though, which is not the same as the type interface.

Answer (score 0):

A class is not in any way an interface, if it implements it. Only logical thing would be if an interface implemented an interface. That should be an interface, itn't it? But it's not possible (only with extending).

Answer (score 0):

No, a class and interface are two different things. Think of an interface as a "coding contract", it can specify things that are required to be in every class that implements it, ensuring that important features will exist in all classes implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the source of the confusion. If class 'Foo' implements interface 'Bar', it can be said that 'Foo' is a 'Bar'. But even though `Foo` is a `Bar` and `Bar` is an interface, `Foo` is not an interface. The "is" relationship is not always transitive.

Comment: I don't believe that the Java language spec formally defines the meaning of "is a".  I probably am guilty of sometimes saying things like, "if you provide a Bar, then..." But, that's conversational shorthand.  The formally correct way of saying it is, "if you provide an _Object that implements Bar_, then..."

Comment: You can use an object of type `Foo` in a context where a `Bar` is expected, such as a variable or parameter declared to be of type `Bar`.  Maybe that's where the confusion comes from?